# how to enable mellanox drivers (network interface card) for vector packet processing (vpp) in Ubuntu 20.04 version?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, dpdk, nic, mellanox, dpdk-pmd

https://github.com/FD.io/vpp

we are unable to add the mellanox drivers in vpp so how to enable the drivers for vpp

1. #apt update

2.#apt upgrade

then, install the following packages

3.#apt install make git cpp gcc libssl-dev libmnl-dev libnuma-dev net-tools rdma-core nasm

4.#git clone -b 20.09 https://github.com/FDio/vpp

5.#cd ~/vpp

6.#make install-dep

7.#make dpdk-install-dev DPDK_MLX5_PMD=y DPDK_MLX5_PMD_DLOPEN_DEPS=y

Next copy the Mellanox library to the /usr/lib directory

8.#cp /opt/vpp/external/x86_64/lib/librte_pmd_mlx5_glue.so* /usr/lib/

Then,make the deb packages that will later be installed

9.#make pkg-deb vpp_uses_dpdk_mlx5_pmd=y DPDK_MLX5_PMD_DLOPEN_DEPS=y

this steps i follwed but im still unable to see the inerfaces in vpp.

so how to enable mellanox drivers for vpp?

Comment: please can anyone help me this issue

Comment: You should move your question to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @Raghavendrach006 default and vendor suggested mode for Mellanox in VPP is RDMA mode. But since you have mentioned about DPDK, can you please clarify what is that you are trying to do? `do you want to run in DPDK mode or RDMA mode?`.

Comment: i need run in DPDK mode @VipinVarghese

Answer (score 1):

By default, MLX4/MLX5 DPDK PMD is not enabled in dpdk makefile in VPP.
In order to enable MLX PMDs, follow the steps below:

1. Edit the dpdk.mk (external/packages/dpdk.mk) for enabling MLX4/MLX5 PMD
   [image]
2. Execute "make install-ext-deps; make build-release"

Comment: @Raghavendrach006 these are right steps to enable DPDK MLX PMD in VPP. Thanks SivaTummala

Comment: Hi siva , we are followed your steps but still we are unable to see the drivers in VPP @Siva Tummala

Comment: @Raghavendrach006 this is very interesting as the same has addressed similar issues in the past. i am open for a live debug session to understand the problem. please share zoom / google meet invite